# AWS Cognito - Logging end user auth activities to CloudWatch Logs

Tags: authentication, logging, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch

I turn on Audit Mode for AWS Cognito to enable Advanced Security Features, as stated here [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-settings-advanced-security.html):

[image]

After that, under `User Pools-Users and Groups-User` section, there are the Last 100 Authentication Events for each user

[image]

I want to re-record this information to a specific log group: `auth-audit-log-group` and log stream: `user-{userId}` in CloudWatch Logs. Reason: CloudWatch allows query based on timestamp. What is the best way to do that?

Pr: I look at `postAuthentication` and `postConfirmation` triggers but they cannot capture failed sign-up and sign-in.